# How can i count number of rows with criterias met in two columns?

Tags: excel, counting, countif

I have 6 columns containing numerical values.

I want to count rows where at least two of the columns in the first 3 columns are above a certain value and where at least two of the columns in the last 3 columns are also above a certain value.

I can check whether the criteria is met in the first three columns for a row with (where the columns are N, P and R)

```
=IF(OR(AND(N2>4000;P2>8000);AND(N2>4000;R2>12);AND(P2>8000;R2>12));"0";"1")
```

which outputs 0 if one of the criterias is met.

I can do the same thing for the last three columns.

How do i turn this into a function that counts all rows where the given criterias are met across all 6 columns?

Comment: Have you considered countifs() ?

Comment: Yes, but I have no clue how to combine above with a countifs

Comment: Can you not use a helper cell to count all 0s e.g. `COUNTIF(IFFormulaCol;0)`. It will then be readable as well as easily verifiable.

Comment: Could you post a data example (input) and the expected output?